# How does react update state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I'm getting a very strange issue that I don't know how to address.

I've got a fairly straightforward method: When a button is pressed it called `toggleInverted()`

```
toggleInverted() {
  if(this.state.inverted){
    this.setState({inverted: false});
  } else{
    console.log("got to else...");
    this.setState({inverted: true});
    console.log(this.state.inverted);
  }
}
```

The inverted field is initialized in the constructor to `false`. However the first time I click the button when I load the page, it doesn't correctly reset the state. The output is:
    `got to else...
    false`.

So somehow it is getting into this else statement, executing the `setState`, and yet not setting inverted to be true...

Is there something about `setState` that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` does not change your components state immediately. Your state change may be asynchronous and thus no guarantee that your console.log statement will print the changed state. `setState` however does always lead to the `render` method being called, so if you console log your state inside the `render` method of your component, your state should be true.

Also, `this.setState({inverted: !this.state.inverted})` is a shorter version of your code snippit

Comment: Thank you! I'll shorten it up as you suggested. I used the longform to be 100% sure it wasn't something there that logic that was messing it up.

Answer (score 1):

**`setState` [may be asynchronous](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)**

Meaning you cannot expect the values of `this.state` to change immediately after `setState` is called.

To quote the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous):

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a
>   pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this
>   method can potentially return the existing value...

---

As an aside, you can figure your code by using the negative expression of the current inverted value as follows:

```
toggleInverted() {
  this.setState({inverted: !this.state.inverted});
}
```